# Laravel Eloquent Relation Query - Get data along with relation attribute

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need help to retrieve eloquent relational data.

Let's say I have this eloquent relation:

#### Model & Relation

Company
Attribute: (id, code, name, status) 
Relation:

```
public function sites(){
   $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Site::class);
}
```

Site 
Attribute: (id, company_id, code, name, status) 
Relation:

```
public function company(){
    $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Company::class);
}
```

#### What I want to retrieve

I want to retrieve all site data along with it's company name, e.g:

```
[
   {
      "id":7,
      "company_id":1,
      "company_name":"Company 1",
      "code":"S001",
      "name":"Site 001",
      "status":"Active"
   },
   {
      "id":8,
      "company_id":1,
      "company_name":"Company 1",
      "code":"S002",
      "name":"Site 002",
      "status":"Active"
   }
]
```

#### What I already tried

1 - I've already tried with this method:

```
$sites = Site::with('company')->get();
dd($sites->toJson());
```

but it gives me:

```
[
   {
      "id":7,
      "company_id":1,
      "code":"S001",
      "name":"Site 001",
      "status":"Active",
      "company":{
         "id":1,
         "code":"C001",
         "name":"Company 1",
         "status":"Active"
      }
   },
   {
      "id":8,
      "company_id":1,
      "code":"S002",
      "name":"Site 002",
      "status":"Active",
      "company":{
         "id":1,
         "code":"C001",
         "name":"Company 1",
         "status":"Active"
      }
   },
]
```

2 - For now, I use this way to get the data. But I think there's another best way without loop the whole data just to get some specific relation attribute:

```
$sites = Site::get();
foreach ($sites as $site){
    $site['company_name'] = $site->company()->first()->name;
}
dd($sites->toJson());
```

#### My question

Actually, how is the best way to get the data I want? Is it possible to not use loop and just use Eloquent relation query? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would be to create an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) on your `Site` model:

```
public function getCompanyNameAttribute()
{
    return optional($this->company)->name;
}
```

^ The `optional()` helper makes it so, that this won't throw an error if a site doesn't have a company. You might not need it depending on your database set up.

You can then add the accessor to [`$appends`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) array in the model, so that it becomes visible in JSON dumps:

`protected $appends = ['company_name'];`

I would also recommend you to eager load the company with sites every time, like you did in your first example - to avoid `n + 1`:

`Site::with('company')->get()`

Additionally, if you'd like to hide the `company` object, you can do that with [`protected $hidden = ['company']`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json) in the model.